# Graphical dataflow composition framework

Tags: java, workflow, dsl, modeling, dataflow

I am interested to embed a [MathWorks Simulink](http://www.mathworks.fr/products/simulink/) like type tool into my application. In this embedded tool units are expressed as blocks with their input and output ports and parameters for each block using my block definition files written in any way that the tool wants. I want the framework to be generic and read the block definitions from somewhere and then allow the user to compose a dataflow of the given blocks based on their definition (preferably comes with graphical editor to do so). I then want the tool to export the user composed dataflow of blocks where I could pragmatically read it in Java (or other languages) and do whatever I need to with it like building an executable version of the given dataflow.

I know at advance level, the exported block compositions can be smart enough to be executable but I am ok with exporting the block composition/topology and the input and outputs connected to each other . In other words, I am NOT looking for a dataflow programming language. I am looking for the just the tool-set that allows graphical composition of dataflows and then export the composition as say a json or something that I could load in a programming languages and do whatever with it.

The above framework/tool is what Simulink does for blocks coming from its different libraries but I need to embedded such thing in my own tool and was wondering what open source project is close to what I want to do. I guess what I want is a dataflow composition framework. Please correct my view of looking at this.

Comment: I think, there is no standard Dataflow Language exists in the known universe, so there are no editors for it. I've created a *prototype* DF system with a friend of mine, and we are using a simple DF script markup language, which we can display using a small PHP app which translates our DF script to GraphViz script.

Answer (score 5):

Data flow languages are special case of (colored) [Petri nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net).  A [colored Petri net](http://daimi.au.dk/CPnets/proxy.php?url=/CPnets/intro/verybrief) consists of a graph of places, each holding colored tokens carrying values (colors is a funny name for "data type", a value is just a color/datatype instance).  Tokens from multiple places combine via transitions to produce tokens in following places; the "transition" can combine the "colors" (e.g, compute values).   So, one might have a token "color" for floating point values, and transitions consisting of add, subtract, multiply, divide; and you can pretty easily model arithmetic data flow (e.g., Simulink) with this.

More importantly, CPNs are amazingly general.  They are filled out with hierarchical CPNs, which give the effect of data-flow subroutines, and allow all kinds of extensions (such as timed-constraints, etc.).

The [Colored Petri Net Tools](http://cpntools.org/) site offers a complete suite of tools for building/editing/displaying and even evaluating arbitrary Colored Petri Nets. (You might not even need to write your Java program to evaluate them!).  It even offers static analysis of such graphs, such as "terminates", etc, which you usually don't get with Matlab or National Instruments style data flow language.

It wouldn't surprise me if there were a Java-based version of the CPN tools; that group has been building such tools for over a decade.  It also wouldn't suprise me if there was a way to constrain the colors and transitions to a specific set, e.g., to the "dataflow" langauge you define, relatively easily.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal would be [Yakindu Statecharts Tool](http://statecharts.org/). I'm not sure though if that would be too complex. But I think it should be mentioned around here. You can define rules and errors are shown, when things are connected that shouldn't be. I think it also looks a bit like what Simulink does, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a sneak peak on J. Paul Morrison's [DrawFBP](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/#DrawFBP). I was unable to draw an edge with it, but it must be my fault.

Also, the best UI I've seen is [moonbase.com](http://moonbase.com/), if I ever write one (I will), it will be similar. Nice preview area, tutorial mode, it's beautiful. I haven't figured out, wheter the editor is available or what's the aim of this project.

---

Last, our DF script language (just to see, what should we hide with a graph editor):

```
redbutton: Button  // we have a button
redbutton.press >> redlamp.on   // it turns the red lamp on
redbutton.press >> greenlamp.off  // and the green off
redbutton.presst >> redmsg.in  // also reports the action

greenbutton: Button  // opposite
greenbutton.press >> greenlamp.on
greenbutton.press >> redlamp.off
greenbutton.press >> greenmsg.in

redlamp: Lamp
greenlamp: Lamp

redmsg: Text
redmsg.value = "red"
redmsg.out >> console.in

greenmsg: Text
greenmsg.value = "green"
greenmsg.out >> console.in

console: Stdout
```

As you can see, there are only 3 elements of the language:

- place a component (name: Type)
- set value of a property (compname.propname = value)
- define a message (srccomp.srcport >> dest.destport)

Of course, a graphics editor should be better. We have only visualizer now.

[image: generated DF graph]

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a tool like this and stumbled upon [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html), a developer library which can be used to build an interactive graph/diagram drawing tool on your own. This does not mean that you have to do all the hard work on your own, since a good starting point is already provided by *com.mxgraph.examples.swing.GraphEditor* in the folder *examples*.

A screenshot of that demo editor

[image]

When exported to the so called *mx Graph Editor File* (*.xme) one actually gets xml. For the example above:

```
<mxGraphModel>
    <root>
        <mxCell id="0" />
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
        <mxCell id="4" parent="1" style="fontSize=24" value="Start"
            vertex="1">
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" height="120.0" width="160.0" x="80.0"
                y="250.0" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="5" parent="1" style="fontSize=24" value="???"
            vertex="1">
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" height="120.0" width="160.0" x="310.0"
                y="480.0" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell edge="1" id="6" parent="1" source="4" style="" target="5"
            value="">
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" relative="1">
                <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="290.0" y="310.0" />
                <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="220.0" y="330.0" />
            </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="9" parent="1" style="fontSize=24" value="Profit"
            vertex="1">
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" height="120.0" width="160.0" x="570.0"
                y="710.0" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell edge="1" id="10" parent="1" source="5" style="" target="9"
            value="">
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" relative="1">
                <mxPoint as="sourcePoint" x="520.0" y="670.0" />
                <mxPoint as="targetPoint" x="490.0" y="840.0" />
            </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
    </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

The parsing of the file using standard XML libraries should not be a problem, so in summary, when all the position information is ignored, one gets a simple dataflow description.

However, please take my suggestion with a grain of salt, since I am also looking for the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following precisesly matches your expectations but you could have a look at [Eclipse eTrice project](http://www.eclipse.org/etrice/) - it has a graphical editor and exports model expressed in their own language. however I don't know how mature this project is in practice and what can be currently done with the models in Java.

you could also review other [modelling projects at Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/listofprojects.php).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me that your users should edit UML activities. So you could build upon [Eclipse Papyrus](http://eclipse.org/papyrus/) and the [Eclipse UML2 API](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2). You need to attach more specific semantics to the activities being edited and restrict the users in what they can edit (for example you don't might want parallel execution via activity fork and join nodes). Executing the edited model than becomes reading in the activity and going through it. If you enter a node, then you just have to call into your node definition. That sounds pretty easy.

Anyway, I follow @mantrid suggestion to have a look at the [eclipse modeling project](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/).

Comment: (+1) for the eclipse modeling project, especially for the [Graphical Editing Framework (GEF)](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). [As it seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617713/running-swt-components-within-a-swing-app?rq=1), one can use SWT in a separate window when the main application is Swing. Promising ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try **Cameleon**: [[http://www.shinoe.org/cameleon][1]](http://www.shinoe.org/cameleon%5d%5b1%5d) which seems to be simple to use. It's a graphical language for functional programming which has a data(work)-flow approach.

Its written in C++ but can call any type of local or distant programs written in any programming language.

It has a multi-scale approach and seems to be turing complete (this is a petri net extension).

sheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should also try YAWL which has a pretty good background in workflow programming in a graphical way, you can see:

1. [http://www.yawlfoundation.org/][1]

See workflow patterns which is a really good theoretical basis, I think, to approach graphical programming.